# Firestore: Data modeling for object tracking application

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

This is my first Firestore – and NoSQL – project, and I'm struggling with modeling my data.

I have a number of objects (in the order of 500 to 1000) that travel physically around the globe. They periodically (about once a day) check in to send their geolocation along with some extra data.

In other words, there are a thousand streams of slowly accumulating tracking data.

How do I best structure my data to optimize for the following query?
For each of the tousand objects, give me the last N tracking locations, sorted from newest to oldest. I assume N to be around 100 to 300.

EDIT: To clarify, this would return about 1000 x (100 to 300) tracking locations. Can this be accomplished without 1000 queries (i.e. one for each of the objects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following database structure should work for your use-case.

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- drivers (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- driverId (document)
   |     |
   |     --- //other driver details
   |
   --- data (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- driverId (document)
   |           |
   |           --- driverData (collection)
   |                 |
   |                 --- driverDataId (document) //Same object as below
   |                       |
   |                       --- geoPoint: [[48.858376° N, 2.294537° E]]
   |                       |
   |                       --- date: Oct 11, 2018 at 6:16:58 PM UTC+3
   |                       |
   |                       --- driverId: "DriverUserId"
   |                       |
   |                       --- //other extra data
   |
   --- allData (collection)
         |
         --- driverDataId (document) //Same object as above
                |
                --- geoPoint: [[48.858376° N, 2.294537° E]]
                |
                --- date: Oct 11, 2018 at 6:16:58 PM UTC+3
                |
                --- driverId: "DriverUserId"
                |
                --- //other extra data
```

> They periodically (about once a day) check in to send their geolocation along with some extra data.

Assuming that you have a model class for the data that the driver is sending once a day, the object that it should be sent to the database, should be sent in **two** differetnt locations:

```
data (collection) -> driverId (document) -> driverData (collection) -> driverDataId (document)
```

and

```
allData (collection) -> driverDataId (document)
```

> For all objects give me the last N tracking locations, sorted from newest to oldest.

To get all those objects a query like this is needed:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference allDataRef = rootRef.collection("allData");
Query query = allDataRef.orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(n);
```

If you want to get also the driver details, you need to make an extra `get()` call, so you can get its details. You can acheive this using the `driverId` that exist as a property within the driver data object.

If you want to get all those object from a single driver, you should use the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference allDataRef = rootRef.collection("data").document(driverId).collecton("driverData");
Query query = allDataRef.orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(n);
```

This practice is called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, i recomand you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). It is for Firebase realtime database but same principle apply to Cloud Firestore.

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

**Edit:**

According to your comment, I uderstand now what you mean. In this case you can consider `allData` collection a feed, in which you should add as you can see, driver data objects. Let's say that `n = 100`. This means that everytime you add a new object after the 100th object, you need to delete the oldest one. So this implies an extra delete operation. In this way you'll keep in that feed only 100 objects of a particular user. And yes, if you have 1000 users and every user has 100 data objects, you'll need to query a collection that has 100k documents. So if you want to have all that data at once, 100k reads will be performed.

**Edit2:**

There is another schema at which I can think at but this implies some tests, because I don't know how big your driver data object can be. So please see my schema below:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- drivers (collection)
         |
         --- driverId (document)
         |
         --- //other driver details
         |
         --- driverData (map)
               |
               --- driverDataId (document) //Same object as below
                     |
                     --- geoPoint: [[48.858376° N, 2.294537° E]]
                     |
                     --- date: Oct 11, 2018 at 6:16:58 PM UTC+3
                     |
                     --- driverId: "DriverUserId"
                     |
                     --- //other extra data
```

As you can see I have changed the `driverData` collection into a `map` within the driver object. In this case, you should also maintain those 100 object within this map. In this case, only 1000 queries are needed, that can return 100k driver data object. But pay atention, the problem is that that the documents have limits. So there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. When we are talking about storing text, you can store pretty much but as your map of objects getts bigger, be careful about this limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestion! I have edited my question for clarity. In terms of your example, I want to retrieve the last N tracking locations for EACH of the 1000 or so drivers.
I think what you are suggesting with the allData collection will give me the last N updates irrespective of the driver.
I am wondering if this can be achieved without sending ~1000 queries to the data collection?

Comment: Yes, that's the exact thing that I was suggesting but according to your comment, I understood what you ment. So please see my updated answer.

Comment: Please see again my updated answer with another approach (**Edit2**). Hope this will help you much more than the previous solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the updates! So I guess the first point for me to take away is that I have to decide on the number N beforehand. It's not something I'll be able to change on the fly – I'll have to recompute the respective collections to contain the new number of updates, from a separate collection where I actually keep ALL the updates.

And just to make sure I understand it correctly: The difference between the two solutions is the number of read operations (and thus the pricing) needed, right? Both solutions only need one request sent to the database, correct?

Comment: "The difference between the two solutions is the number of read operations (and thus the pricing) needed, right?" Yes, that's correct! "Both solutions only need one request sent to the database, correct?" Yes, that's right. It doesn't matter how many requests do you make, a single connection to the database is made.